CodePipeline Integration with on prem Bitbucket Server
Using steps in https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-codepipeline-bitbucket-integration am trying to integrate CodePipeline with on-premises Bitbucket Server.
When I push the code to repo am getting following error. I am not sure what I am still missing.
 *`File downloaded successfully: <ref *2> IncomingMessage {    
  _events: 
    close: [Function: onclose],
    error: [Function: onerror],
    data: undefined,
    end: [ [Function: responseOnEnd], [Function: onend] ],
    readable: undefined,
    finish: [Function: onfinish]
  
WARN    Are you using a Stream of unknown length as the Body of a PutObject request? Consider using Upload instead from @aws-sdk/lib-storage.
WARN    An error was encountered in a non-retryable streaming request.
INFO    Exiting with error NotImplemented: A header you provided implies functionality that is not implemented
    at throwDefaultError (/var/runtime/node_modules/@aws-sdk/node_modules/@smithy/smithy-client/dist-cjs/index.js:838:20)
    at /var/runtime/node_modules/@aws-sdk/node_modules/@smithy/smithy-client/dist-cjs/index.js:847:5
    at de_CommandError (/var/runtime/node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-s3/dist-cjs/index.js:4756:14)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async /var/runtime/node_modules/@aws-sdk/node_modules/@smithy/middleware-serde/dist-cjs/index.js:35:20
    at async /var/runtime/node_modules/@aws-sdk/middleware-signing/dist-cjs/index.js:225:18
    at async /var/runtime/node_modules/@aws-sdk/node_modules/@smithy/middleware-retry/dist-cjs/index.js:320:38
    at async /var/runtime/node_modules/@aws-sdk/middleware-flexible-checksums/dist-cjs/index.js:173:18
    at async /var/runtime/node_modules/@aws-sdk/middleware-sdk-s3/dist-cjs/index.js:97:20
    at async /var/runtime/node_modules/@aws-sdk/middleware-sdk-s3/dist-cjs/index.js:120:14 {
  '$fault': 'client',
  '$metadata': 
    httpStatusCode: 501,
    requestId: 'G64RMGHEPWVDE',
    extendedRequestId: 'FTZNy/uEqwgkrWH3XP/QIIiCIZAc5f+ZxCG3tFJp7QhFrCopRunG5ScmqfMxbpWus3o6cuXoC1M=',
    cfId: undefined
  
  Code: 'NotImplemented',
  Header: 'Transfer-Encoding',
  RequestId: 'G64RMGHYPWVDE',
  HostId: 'FTZNy/uEqwgkrWH3XP/QIIiCIZAc5f3tFJp7QhFrCopRunG5ScmqfMxbpWus3o6cuXoC1M='*

I have updated bucket policies and IAM role.
Bucket Policy:
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxx:role/lambda-executionrole"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:Get*",
                "s3:List*",
                "s3:Put*",
                "s3:Delete*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucketname",
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucketname/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}

Lambda IAM has S3 full access and AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole managed policies attached to it and custom policy have below premissions:
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetBucket*",
                "s3:ListBucket*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucketname"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Sid": "S3BucketPolicy"
        },
        {
            "Action": [
                "s3:AbortMultipartUpload",
                "s3:GetObject*",
                "s3:PutObject*",
                "s3:DeleteObject*",
                "s3:RestoreObject",
                "s3:ListMultipartUploadParts"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucketname/*"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow"
        },
        {
            "Action": [
                "kms:decrypt"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:kms:us-east-1:xxxxxxxxx:key/xxxxxxxxxxxxx9"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow"
        }
    ]
}

This is my code:
 import {S3Client, PutObjectCommand} from "@aws-sdk/client-s3"
 import axios from "axios"
 import crypto from 'node:crypto';
    
 // Initialize S3 client
 const s3Client = new S3Client({ region: process.env.AWS_REGION });
    
    /**
     * Convert an object keys to lowercase
     * @param {object} request - this is a object to convert the keys to lowercase
     * @returns {object} - return a new object with keys in lower case
     */
    function normalizeObject(inputObject) {
        console.log('info', '>>> normalizeObject()');
    
        const requestKeys = Object.keys(inputObject);
    
        let outputObject = {};
        for (let i = 0; i < requestKeys.length; i++) {
            outputObject[requestKeys[i].toLowerCase()] = inputObject[requestKeys[i]];
        }
    
        console.log('info', '<<< normalizeObject()');
        return outputObject;
    }
    
    /**
     * Download the repository content as a zip file
     * @param {object} repoConfig - this is a object containing the config for the repository
     * @param {object} proxy - this is a object containing the web proxy configuration
     * @returns {stream} - return a stream containing the repository zip file
     */
    async function downloadFile(repoConfig, proxy) {
        console.log('info', '>>> downloadFile()');
        console.log(`proxy: ${JSON.stringify(proxy)}`);
    
        const params = {
            proxy,
            method: 'get',
            baseURL: repoConfig.serverUrl,
            url: `/rest/api/latest/projects/${repoConfig.projectName}/repos/${repoConfig.repoName}/archive?at=refs/heads/${repoConfig.branch}&format=zip`,
            responseType: 'stream',
            headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${repoConfig.token}`
            }
        };
        console.log('Request params:', JSON.stringify(params, null, 2));
    
        try {
            const resp = await axios.request(params);
            console.log('info', '<<< downloadFile()');
            return resp.data;
        }
        catch (err) {
            console.log('error', err);
            throw new Error(err);
        }
    }
    
    /**
     * Check BitBucket Server Signature
     * @param {string} signingSecret - this is the signing secret for the BitBucket Server webhook
     * @param {string} signature - this is the signatured applied by BitBucket to the message
     * @param {object} body - this is the message body
     * @returns {boolean} - return true or false
     */
    function checkSignature(signingSecret, signature, body) {
        console.log('info', '>>> signingSecret()');
        const hash = crypto.createHmac('sha256', signingSecret).update(body).digest('hex');
    
        const signatureHash = signature.split('=');
        if (signatureHash[1] === hash) {
            console.log('info', '<<< signingSecret()');
            return true;
        }
    
        console.log('info', '<<< signingSecret()');
        return false;
    }
    
    /**
     * Generate a response for API Gateway
     * @param {string} statusCode - HTTP status code to return
     * @param {string} detail - this is message detail to return
     * @returns {object} - return the formatted response object
     */
    function responseToApiGw(statusCode, detail) {
        if (!statusCode) {
            throw new TypeError('responseToApiGw() expects at least argument statusCode');
        }
        if (statusCode !== '200' && !detail) {
            throw new TypeError('responseToApiGw() expects at least arguments statusCode and detail');
        }
    
        let body = {};
        if (statusCode === '200' && detail) {
            body = {
                statusCode: statusCode,
                message: detail
            };
        } else if (statusCode === '200' && !detail) {
            body = {
                statusCode: statusCode
            };
        } else {
            body = {
                statusCode: statusCode,
                fault: detail
            };
        }
        let response = {
            statusCode: statusCode,
            body: JSON.stringify(body),
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'POST, GET',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept'
            }
        };
        return response;
    }
    
    export const handler = async (event) => {
        try {
            console.log(`Incoming event: ${JSON.stringify(event)}`);
            const eventBody = JSON.parse(event.body);
            console.log('eventBody');
            console.log(eventBody);
            // Normalize headers
            const normalizedHeaders = normalizeObject(event.headers);
    
            // Respond to test event
            if ('x-event-key' in normalizedHeaders && normalizedHeaders['x-event-key'] === 'diagnostics:ping') {
                return responseToApiGw(200, 'Webhook configured successfully');
            }
    
            // Validate message signature
            if (!(checkSignature(process.env.BITBUCKET_SECRET, normalizedHeaders['x-hub-signature'], event.body))) {
                console.log('Invalid webhook message signature');
                return responseToApiGw(401, 'Signature is not valid');
            }
            console.log('Signature validated successfully');
    
            if (!(eventBody.changes[0].ref.type === 'BRANCH')) {
                console.log('Invalid event type');
                throw new Error('Invalid event type');
            }
    
            const repoConfig = {
                serverUrl: process.env.BITBUCKET_SERVER_URL,
                projectName: eventBody.repository.project.key,
                repoName: eventBody.repository.name,
                branch: eventBody.changes[0].ref.displayId,
                token: process.env.BITBUCKET_TOKEN
            };
    
            let proxy;
            if (process.env.WEBPROXY_HOST && process.env.WEBPROXY_PORT) {
                proxy = {
                    host: process.env.WEBPROXY_HOST,
                    port: process.env.WEBPROXY_PORT
                };
                
    
            }
    
            // Download the repository package from Bitbucket Server
            const file = await downloadFile(repoConfig, proxy);
            console.log('File downloaded successfully:', file);
    
            // Create a PutObjectCommand with the zipped repository package key and file
            const uploadCommand = new PutObjectCommand({
                Bucket: process.env.S3BUCKET,
                Key: `${repoConfig.projectName}/${repoConfig.repoName}/${repoConfig.branch}.zip`,
                Body: file,
                ServerSideEncryption: "AES256"
            });
    
            // Upload the repository package to S3 bucket
    //        await s3Client.send(uploadCommand).promise();
            const s3Upload = await s3Client.send(uploadCommand);
    
            console.log(s3Upload);
    
            console.log('Exiting successfully');
            return responseToApiGw(200, 'success');
        }
        catch (err) {
            console.log('Exiting with error', err);
            return responseToApiGw(500, 'Some weird thing happened');
        }
    }


it worked. add  your code with below  and make sure you have s3 permission in bucket policy and Lambda execution role


// Create an upload with the zipped repository package key and file
const upload = new Upload({
client: s3Client,
params: {
Bucket: process.env.S3BUCKET,
Key: ${repoConfig.projectName}/${repoConfig.repoName}/${repoConfig.branch}.zip,
Body: file,
ServerSideEncryption: "AES256"
}
});
// Monitor the upload process
upload.on("httpUploadProgress", (progress) => {
console.log(progress);


Would be great, if you edit you answer and format the code correctly. This way, it's really hard to read...
